# Symfony FosUser, @Exclude properties

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using `FosUserBundle` and i have my `User.php` class.

But i'm using `JmsSerializer`, and i need to `@Exclude` some properties from the base `User.php` in the Fos%UserBundle, like `username_canonical`.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @Exclude
 */
protected $usernameCanonical;
```

I need to override these property in MY User.php class ? Or is there an other method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only affect the metadata for the actual class that you are working on so for third party classes you will need to create other mapping.

The following is taken from [this issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/78).

```
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: FOS\UserBundle
                path: %kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB

# %kernel.root_dir%/serializer/FOSUB/Model.User.yml
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: NONE
    properties:
        emailCanonical:
            exclude: true
        usernameCanonical:
            exclude: true
```